# The continuous image of a First Countable Space need not be First Countable (Willard 16.B.1)

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, second-countable, first-countable

In Stephen Willard's *General Topology* appears the following exercise:

> A quotient of a second countable space need not be second countable (for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $I_n$ be a copy of $[0,1]$ and let $X$ be the disjoint union of the spaces $I_n$. Now identify the left-hand endpoints of all intervals $I_n$. The resulting space $Z$ is not first countable at the distinguished point, and hence not second countable, although $X$ is second countable.

**EDIT**: What I had tried was completely misleading and led nowhere, so I decided to delete it.

Comment: You have things the wrong way around: B([0]) is countable - you've defined it so - but it is not a neighbourhood basis, Look again at your attempt to proof it is: the infimum you mention can be 0 and then you'll have a nbhd B which does not contain any $B_{1/n}([0])$.   ...

Comment: ... You need to show that for any countable collection of nbhds there is another which does not contain any of them. (I'm assuming that by "distances of the pre-image of B under the canonical projection to each corresponding {0}×{j}" you mean a distance d > 0  such that [0,d)x{j} is contained in the pre-image of B. Note that these distances form a sequence of positive numbers and use a diagonal argument.)

Comment: It is still countable, so if it were a nbhd. basis you would have proved the opposite of what you're trying to do. But actually the change is insignificant, if either version were a basis the other would be too.

Comment: A quotient map with closed equivalence classes can  map a second-countable space to a space which is not even  first-countable. Let $ \Bbb R$ have the usual topology, and identify the integers to a point $p\not \in \Bbb R.$  The point $p,$ in  the space $(\Bbb R \backslash \Bbb Z)\cup \{p\}.$ does not have a countable nbhd base. (Example from General Topology by R. Engeling.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is wrong because that infimum of the distances of the preimage of $B$ can be $0$.

You can prove that $Z$ is not first countable by using a diagonal argument. From the definition of quotient topology, every neighbourhood of $\pi(0)$ can be identified with a sequence of intervals $[0,x_n)\subset I_n$. Thus, every neighbourhood of $\pi(0)$ can be thought as a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, with every $x_n \in (0,1]$.

Therefore, suppose that there is a countable basis $\{B_n | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ of the form
\begin{align}
B_1 &= x_1^1, x_2^1, \dots, x_n^1 \dots \\
B_2 &= x_1^2, x_2^2, \dots, x_n^2 \dots\\
&\vdots \\
B_n &= x_1^n, x_2^n, \dots, x_n^n \dots \\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Then we can take the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with every $y_k < x_k^k$ so that the neighbourhood $U = y_1,y_2,...,y_n,...$ does not contain any of the $B_n$.